# CMake pybind11 cannot create target because another target with the same name already exists, how to bypass?

Tags: cmake, pybind11, python-extensions

I have code which successfully runs. Its CmakeLists.txt is:

`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(rotapro3)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
add_executable(rotapro3 main.cpp)`:

I want to use pybind for this project, and following the instructions, I add these lines:

```
add_subdirectory(pybind)
pybind11_add_module(rotapro3 main.cpp)
```

It successfully launches, but I am getting an error:

```
 add_executable cannot create target "rotapro3" because another target with
  the same name already exists.  The existing target is a module library
  created in source directory "C:/Users/Alex/Dropbox/rotapro3".
```

I barely have knowledge in CMake. How could I rewrite these lines to allow me use `add_executable`?

UPDATE:

I have another more complex case:

```
    set(SOURCE_FILES
        unit_test/geometry/monomer_test.cpp
        unit_test/geometry/monomer_test.hpp
        unit_test/geometry/polymer_test.cpp
        unit_test/geometry/polymer_test.hpp
        unit_test/geometry/unit_box_test.cpp
        unit_test/geometry/unit_box_test.hpp
        unit_test/geometry/rect_shape_3d_test.cpp
        unit_test/geometry/rect_shape_3d_test.hpp
        src/general/guard.cpp
        src/general/guard.hpp
        src/general/fmt_enum.hpp
        src/general/string_format.cpp
        src/general/string_format.hpp
        src/geometry/monomer.cpp
        src/geometry/monomer.hpp
        src/geometry/polymer.cpp
        src/geometry/polymer.hpp
        src/geometry/unit_box.cpp
        src/geometry/unit_box.hpp
        src/geometry/rect_shape_3d.cpp
        src/geometry/rect_shape_3d.hpp
        )
include_directories(src/general)
include_directories(src/geometry)
include_directories(unit_test/general)
include_directories(unit_test/geometry)

add_executable(
        grapoli_lap ${SOURCE_FILES}
        unit_test/general/string_format_test.cpp
        unit_test/general/string_format_test.hpp
        unit_test/geometry/monomer_test.cpp
        unit_test/geometry/monomer_test.hpp
        unit_test/geometry/polymer_test.cpp
        unit_test/geometry/polymer_test.hpp
        unit_test/geometry/unit_box_test.cpp
        unit_test/geometry/unit_box_test.hpp
        unit_test/geometry/rect_shape_3d_test.cpp
        unit_test/geometry/rect_shape_3d_test.cpp
)

add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(grapoli_lap grapoli_lib.cpp)

target_link_libraries(grapoli_lap gtest gtest_main)
```

I am getting the same error.

Comment: My solution was to use this form: add_subdirectory(pybind11)
target_link_libraries(grapoli_lap PRIVATE pybind11::embed

Comment: If you found another working solution, I encourage you to write up a quick answer post (marking it as *accepted*) showing the code, and explaining how you fixed the issue. This way, future visitors to your post can benefit from the solution, and understand what fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In CMake, you cannot have two targets with the *same* name. Because the [`pybind11_add_module()`](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html#pybind11-add-module) is similar to `add_library()`, you should use this command to create a library target. You can name this library target `rotapro3`. Then, you can create your executable target, named something else (like `rotapro3_exe`):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(rotapro3)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_subdirectory(pybind)
# Create the library rotapro3 target here.
pybind11_add_module(rotapro3 example.cpp)

# Create your executable target (with a different name).
add_executable(rotapro3_exe main.cpp)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you help, but I didn't understand. How should I create the rotapro3 target without add_executable() command?

Comment: @ragnarrok I modified my answer to better explain how the targets should have **different** names. Hope that helps! I encourage you to read through the linked documentation as well.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please help with a little bit more advanced case, see updated question:

Comment: @ragnarrok The same rule applies for your complex case: Two CMake targets *cannot have the same name*. Just rename one of them so their names aren't the same. If necessary, you can then *link* the Python-bindings library created by the `pybind11_add_module` call to your other executable, as shown in my example.

Comment: But pybind11_add_module(grapoli_lap grapoli_lib.cpp) - grapoli_lib.cpp is unique target. I understand that problem is in grapoli_lab. But if I change this name for any of the cases, I am getting the error that targets could not be found

Comment: @ragnarrok Well yes, if you change the name of the executable target (`grapoli_lap`) for example, you will likewise have to change its name everywhere that the executable target name is used *elsewhere* in your CMake file tree.

Comment: Sorry it looks simple yet somehow I have difficulty to comprehend this. So what you saying is that I just change grapoli_lap filename to any other name? I tried the simpler example with your suggestion, unfortunately, got some errors as well that it cannot be linked. Would you mind if I asked you another example, sorry for your time

Comment: @ragnarrok The `add_executable` command and `pybind11_add_module` both create CMake targets, so you must change the target name (first argument to each command) such that the target names to do overlap. There is no need to change any *file* names.

Comment: @ragnarrok As a side note, I don't see many cases in which the Python-bindings library is *linked to* an executable, so it is likely used as a stand-alone library. So I'm removing the `target_link_libraries()` portion of my answer; it doesn't seem to be a necessary part of the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I just changed:  pybind11_add_module(grapoli). The error I get is : CMake Error at pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:131 (add_library):
  No SOURCES given to target: grapoli

Comment: If I add target_link_libraries, the error I get : CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:83 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "grapoli" of type MODULE_LIBRARY may not be linked into another
  target.  One may link only to INTERFACE, OBJECT, STATIC or SHARED
  libraries, or to executables with the ENABLE_EXPORTS property set.

Comment: @ragnarrok The error message is pretty clear... The `pybind11_add_module()` command takes at least **two** arguments: the target *name* and the *source* file(s). Again, please refer to my example, or the examples in the linked documentation.